# Extract from Discontinues Range First and Last Cell Addres

Tags: vba, range, cell, extract

There is a discontinues range object:
     `Range("$C$3:$C$5,$C$100:$C$64000")`

how to get first and last cell of it?
`firstCell = ("C1")
lastCell = ("C64000")`

asumming any cell in that range could be blank, or even hidden?
The preferred way from my side would be to use some property like "last cell", "first cell" or similar and avoiding regular expressions or loops but is there any property like that? or method to get such info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are working with non-contiguous cells, you have to work with their [Range.Areas property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196243.aspx). By paring down the unioned range to the visible cells and non-blanks (e.g. constants) with the [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) and [xlCellTyp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) you can deal with the first or last Area to get the properties you are looking for.

```
Sub main()
    Dim firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range
    Set firstCell = first_non_blank_visible_cell(Range("$C$3:$C$5,$C$100:$C$64000"))
    Set lastCell = last_non_blank_visible_cell(Range("$C$3:$C$5,$C$100:$C$64000"))
    Debug.Print firstCell.Address
    Debug.Print lastCell.Address
End Sub

Function first_non_blank_visible_cell(rng As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    With rng.Areas(1)
        Set first_non_blank_visible_cell = .Cells(1)
    End With
End Function

Function last_non_blank_visible_cell(rng As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    With rng.Areas(rng.Areas.Count)
        Set last_non_blank_visible_cell = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
    End With
End Function
```

I have looked for xlCellTypeConstants because you specified non-blanks and formulas do not leave blanks; they leave zero-length strings. If formulas are involved then some minor modification may be in order to incorporate xlCellTypeFormulas.

If your non-contiguous range included something like D8:X8, there may be some discussion as to whether X8 or C64000 would be considered the 'last cell' but you are only referencing a single column so that point is moot for the moment.